# Play two different sound files from two different buttons?

Tags: java, android, file, audio, button

I tried searching for this in many places, but could not find an answer. I am making an app with a set of image buttons that have the alphabet on them. I want to be able to click the letter A, and hear sound file A. If I click letter B, I want to hear sound file B. So far I only have letters A and B, and sound files A and B. When I run my code, I can only hear the sound for button A, and when I press letter B, Nothing happens. This is my code:

```
    package com.android.nishad.learn.hindi;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    public class AlphabetActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       MediaPlayer mp;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet);

          ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
          btn.setOnClickListener(this);

       }

       public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lettera);
          mp.start();
          while (mp.isPlaying()) { 
             // do nothing 
          };
          mp.release();
       }



       public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet);

          ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
          btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

       }

       public void onClick1(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.letterb);
          mp.start();
          while (mp.isPlaying()) { 
             // do nothing 
          };
          mp.release();
       }
    };
```

Comment: You can't just throw an `onCreate1()` method in there and expect it to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.android.nishad.learn.hindi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class AlphabetActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   MediaPlayer mp;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet);

      ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
      btn.setOnClickListener(this);

      ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
      btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

   }

   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
       switch(v.getId()) 
       {
         case R.id.imageButton1:
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lettera);
             break;
         case R.id.imageButton2:
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.letterb);
             break;
         default:
             return;
       }

      mp.start();
      while (mp.isPlaying()) { 
         // do nothing 
      }
      mp.release();
   }
}
```

Comment: @GurpeetSingh No problem! If you have any specific questions about what I did feel free to ask!

Comment: Um, the `while(mp.isPlaying())` loop is *not* a good idea and will most likely cause your app to stop responding.

Comment: @kcoppock I agree. I'm sure he'll do something more appropriate as he continues to develop his app. He may also want to implement something for onPause() so that the music stops playing when he backs out of his Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Methods `onCreate1` and `onClick1` are useless as they are never invoked.  Instead you should put all the initialisation code in your `onCreate` method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet);

    findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton2).setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int rawid = 0;
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButton1: rawid = R.raw.lettera; break;
        case R.id.imageButton2: rawid = R.raw.letterb; break;

        defalt: return;    //do nothing if none of our buttons;
    }

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawid);
    mp.start();
    while (mp.isPlaying()) { 
        // do nothing 
    };
   mp.release();
}
```

Note however that this is a very inefficient way of handling it.  Instead you should have one MediaPlayer instance and then use it to play various sounds as needed.  Creating a new MediaPlayer every time a button is pressed is a waste of resources.

Comment: thanks, I see your point about this being a waste of resources, so I will now create only one mp. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

  switch(v.getId()){

  case R.id.R.id.imageButton1:
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lettera);
          break;

  case R.id.R.id.imageButton2:
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.letterb);
          break;
  }
          mp.start();
          while (mp.isPlaying()) { 
             // do nothing 
          };
          mp.release();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove those `onCreate1()` and `onClick1()` methods. `onClick()` method is enough to receive click events for all the buttons in your layout. You can do this using the `view.getId()` method. And for playing sounds I'd recommend using the [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) class, which has a very clear interface for such purposes. Hope this helps.