# How to Play two Different sound on two different buttons?

Tags: android, media-player, soundpool

I have 2 sound clips 19 sec each on the click of button1 Soundclip1 should play and on the click of button2 the playing Soundclip1 should stop and Soundclip2 should start..
Please help me i am stuck.
i research about this a lot but my problem is both of the sound playing simultaneously....

Please....
I have refered this [Android Media Player Wont Play After Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001587/android-media-player-wont-play-after-stop) and [Stop the prevoius sound before starting a new sound in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059787/stop-the-prevoius-sound-before-starting-a-new-sound-in-my-android-app)

Comment: ss this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507062/play-two-different-sound-files-from-two-different-buttons

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555637/grid-view-and-media-player-on-click/21556442#21556442

Comment: You can combine this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560606/music-play-but-not-pause-on-android/21560726#21560726 with my above link.

Comment: did you work on it,post code

Comment: Sory Rajashree but it is giving an error on MediaPlayer.create...

Comment: case R.id.ibPlayh:    ibPlay.startAnimation(aBellPlay);
if(ibPlay.isPressed()){     
i++;
}
else if(i > 1){
mpNamyoho.reset();
 }
mpNamyoho.start();
budhamnamyo(mpBuddhamKsharanam);
case R.id.ibPlayh2:        ibPlay2.startAnimation(aBellPlay2);
if(ibPlay2.isPressed()){
j++;
}
   
    else if(j > 1){
     mpNamyoho.reset();
     }
    mpBuddhamKsharanam.start();
    budhamnamyo(mpNamyoho);
protected void budhamnamyo(MediaPlayer mp) {  
  if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
   if(ibPlay.isPressed()){
   mpBuddhamKsharanam.stop();
   }
   else if(ibPlay2.isPressed()){
    mpNamyoho.stop();
    }
}

Comment: this code works only once if i press button another time both the sound clip are not playing

Comment: actually sound clips are 19 sec long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.one);
final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.two);

Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById (R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp1.start();
        mp2.pause();
        mp2.seekTo(0);
    }
});

Button btn1 = (Button)this.findViewById (R.id.button2);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp1.pause();
        mp1.seekTo(0);
        mp2.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ya but it is played only once not all the time

Comment: @Abhi I have tried similar code. Its working. Once try.

Comment: Ya dear but i want to start the clip from the begning.. it actually pauses Please Help me i am a newbie in android

Comment: @Abhi Use **mp2.stop();** instead of **mp2.pause();**. Similarly for **mp1.pause();**

Comment: I tried this also Kanwaljit but after being stop it doesn't play next time.. its a big issue i need to play the music and stop the music n.. number of times means according my button click ..

Comment: Kunwaljit i have tried Soundpool also but it supports sound clip upto 5sec only not more than that and my soundclips are 19 sec long\